# HANDLE in place of CWnd*? (MFC)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, mfc, type-conversion, handle

I have a piece of code in an MFC program that looks like this:

```
    HANDLE newhandle = m_hWnd;    //A

    //draw the bitmap image on the window        
    BITMAP* bi = new BITMAP;
    CBitmap bmp;
    bmp.Attach(transferbitmap);
    CClientDC dc(newhandle);      //B
    //...
    //...
    //...
```

On line 'A', I create a HANDLE named newhandle, and set it to **m_hWnd**, **which is of type CWnd***.  This line alone compiles (using Visual Studio 2010) fine and seems to work.  However, looking at line 'B', when I try to use newhandle in place of m_hWnd, I get the compilation error:

> error C2664: 'CClientDC::CClientDC(CWnd*)' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'HANDLE' to 'CWnd*'

When I use m_hWnd in place of newhandle, the program compiles and runs fine.

My question(s) is(are), why does the compiler let me set newhandle to a CWnd*, but when I try to use it an error occurs?  Furthermore, is there a way to use a non-MFC window handle to replace m_hWnd, because I'm trying to remove all MFC specific code from the lower levels of my code?

Comment: HANDLE is a typedef of void*, that's why you can assign another pointer to it. However, are you sure that m_hWnd is a CWnd* and not an HWND?

Comment: HANDLE and CWnd* are not interchangeable! The former is a system information handle while the latter is the actual pointer in memory. As of the answer to your question, @roger_rowland answered it.

Comment: @roger_rowland Here is it's declaration in the class: `CWnd* m_hWnd;`

Comment: CWnd* m_hWnd is confusing, it is better to rename it: CWnd* m_pWnd. With your variables, correct way is: `HANDLE newhandle = m_hWnd->m_hWnd;` - really strange code!

Comment: @AlexFarber I agree that his naming convention is weird and that he ought to rename, but generally, I recommend avoiding using the `CWnd::m_hWnd` member directly, in lieu of `CWnd::GetSafeHwnd()`.